# Excel Count Cells before text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have a holiday sheet and wish to add up the number of hours for each holiday type, so for example

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | L | N | Type | Name | E | L | N | Type | Name |
| 8 |  |  | Holiday | J Blogs | 8 | - | - | Lieu | H Potter |

I would like to count across the row for each holiday type i.e holiday, lieu, unpaid
then i want to count the hours in the 3 cells before each holiday type for the holiday month.

i should then end up with something along the lines of

| Holiday | Lieu | Unpaid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 8 | 16 |

This would be for around 400 people each row is for one person.

Thanks

Comment: So can you explain how you derived 32, 8 and 16 from given sample data?

Comment: This is an example of what it looks like, but would be for a whole month, if there was 3 days of holiday it would add upto 32, A To E is 1st day F to J is 2nd second day and so on

Comment: so A to E = 1st day of month, F to J = 2nd day of month etc.? Could there be more rows then if two persons went on holiday on the first day of the month?

Answer (score 0):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--($D$2:$AN$2=E5)*($A$2:$AL$2),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr i have tried this and it does not work, just reports 0, also the value maybe anything from 1 to 8 depending how many hours booked off, not every cell will have a value

Comment: What formula you tried as per your sample data? Did you try exact like as my screenshot?

Comment: Yes, just changed cell reverences, =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--($E$19:$EZ$19=FB19)*($B$19:$EX$19),0))   i had a type in the forumla hence the 0 but now im getting 24 instead of 32 (how do i create new line on here) Col A is the name so ignored.

Comment: i think i have fixed this with can someone verify ?  =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--($D$2:$AN$2=D5)*($A$2:$AJ$2),0))+SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--($D$2:$AN$2=D5)*($B$2:$AK$2),0))++SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--($D$2:$AN$2=D5)*($C$2:$AL$2),0))